# ServiceStack default Razor view with service

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I want to host a very simple razor page inside a self host SS app.

I need the / path to resolve to the default.cshtml  - this works out of the box.

But i need to access the user auth session inside the view. To do this I am guessing I need a service to create the model for default.cshtml

Everything I have tried so far doesn't work and I can't create a DefaultRequest with route / as that isn't allowed.

Anyone got any clues as to what I need to do?

I have tried with fall back route but no luck:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class Fallback
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultService : Service
{
    public DefaultService ()
    {
    }

    public object Get(Fallback request){
        return new HttpResult() // #6
        {
            View = "Rockstars"  // #1
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your typed UserAuth session is directly accessible in your Razor Views base [ViewPageBase with base.SessionAs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8dcbbdb7dbe20fd3201cde100370564e8577a019/src/ServiceStack.Razor/ViewPageBase.cs#L449), e.g:

```
@{
    var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
}
```

You've also got access to your dynamic session bag with `base.SessionBag` as well as  `base.IsAuthenticated` to determine if the user is authenticated or not.

### [Fallback Route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route)

In order to invoke a Service to handle your default page you need to use a [Fallback Route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route), e.g:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class DefaultPage
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

A Fallback Service can be used to handle every unmatched request including the root `/` page.

Comment: I marked this as the answer in a moment of excitement but it's not actually working for / it does for /t or /xyz but not /

Comment: @iwayneo Did you include the `*` wildcard path at the end i.e. `/{Path*}`?

Comment: Got it working! Xamarin Studio was doing some dodgy caching :)